# What did Tsunozaki Taki say?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

In chapter 86 of Shokugeki no Soma as Yukihira was about to start whipping up some mad beef stew, this happened (roughly went like this):

> Soma: You were Tsunozaki Taki senpai... right?
>
> Tsuno: Huh? (What's with this guy?! He just went and talked to me normally!)
>
> Soma: It seems you've been saying lots about me. I'll listen to your complaints, after I finish serving my dish!!!!

I've read through this bit quite a few times, and I still have no clue what Soma is referring to when he says "seems you've been talking smack about me". I didn't even know she existed until that chapter. Maybe I'm missing something crucial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ch 85, pg 6- Taki says that,

> *"The headband guy comes from a special-of-the-day downtown family restaurant. Moreover, he's only transferred here for only half a year. That's no good"*

Soma overhears this and replies in the next chapter that, *"I'll listen to your complaints after I finish serving my dish"*

Comment: I'm a complete noob somehow I skipped chapter 85 and never noticed until now lol